# Why downloaded excel file is not containg any data ? the file is empty

Tags: java, servlets

hello everyone i have created one Servlet file. it is downloading as a excel file but not containing any data in it while the code is made build for writing a data in excel file. Basically i have done this steps :-
1. access the data from the database
2.print that data to excel file. 
now up to this working as per the expectation but now at time of excel file gets downloaded. that time it is a blank excel file no data contains in that file. Why it is so Please Shed some light i have just started learning JAVA and SERVLET really new to this.

```
package servletProject;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



@WebServlet("/ExcelFile")
public class CSVServlet extends HttpServlet {       
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String emails = "xyz@gmail.com";

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)      throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        FileWriter writer =null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        Connection con=null;
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        try {
            String fileName = emails+"data.csv";
            System.out.println(fileName);
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
            if (mimeType == null) {
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
            ConnectionClass cn = new ConnectionClass();
            con = cn.connectDb();

         System.out.println("fileName"+fileName);

             writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
            //Write the CSV file header
            CSVUtils.writeLine(writer,Arrays.asList("NAME","email"));
             ps = con.prepareStatement("select firstName,email from employees");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("firstName"));
                 CSVUtils.writeLine(writer,Arrays.asList(rs.getString("firstName"),rs.getString("email")));

            }

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
             try{ rs.close();ps.close();con.close();}catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}



// DB connection File
public class ConnectionClass {


    public Connection connectDb() {

        Connection con=null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
             con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels","root","root");  
        }catch (Exception e) {
            con=null;
        }

        if(con!=null)
            System.out.println("connected");
        else
            System.out.println("not connected");

        return con;
    }
}


//CSVUtil Files

package servletProject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;

public class CSVUtils {

    private static final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ',';

    public static void writeLine(Writer w, List<String> values) throws IOException {
        writeLine(w, values, DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, ' ');
    }

    public static void writeLine(Writer w, List<String> values, char separators) throws IOException {
        writeLine(w, values, separators, ' ');
    }

    // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180
    private static String followCVSformat(String value) {

        String result = value;
        if (result.contains("\"")) {
            result = result.replace("\"", "\"\"");
        }
        return result;

    }

    public static void writeLine(Writer w, List<String> values, char separators, char customQuote) throws IOException {

        boolean first = true;

        // default customQuote is empty

        if (separators == ' ') {
            separators = DEFAULT_SEPARATOR;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String value : values) {
            if (!first) {
                sb.append(separators);
            }
            if (customQuote == ' ') {
                sb.append(followCVSformat(value));
            } else {
                sb.append(customQuote).append(followCVSformat(value)).append(customQuote);
            }

            first = false;
        }
        sb.append("\n");
        w.append(sb.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: You should break this down into smaller and better digestable problems

Comment: if i break this code then it will be harder to understand the whole code.

Comment: ... but you will better find out where the problem occurs ...

Comment: It appears you are writing the CSV file to a file on the server, of the name "xyz@gmail.comdata.csv" and are not writing it to the connection.  You need to either write the stream to the response.getOutputStream() or else copy the file to  response.getOutputStream().  The second is potentially better, because in that case you can call response.setContentLength() first with the exact number of bytes in the file.

Comment: ok i'll make it to try... are you good in servlet?

Comment: @Jamie you explained really well but please try to show me with example. or you can edit my code. but please try to show me with the code because i'm already making so much mistakes because i'm new to java and especially to servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that writes to the response's outputstream.
Note that I changed 'writer' to be an OutputStream instead of a FileWriter, as that is what you get from response.getOutputStream().

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)      throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    OutputStream writer = response.getOutputStream();
    :
    //Write the CSV file header 
    //(no change from your code here.)
    CSVUtils.writeLine(writer,Arrays.asList("NAME","email"));
```

This requires you to alter your CSVUtils class to accept an OutputStream instead of a Writer object, but there isn't much difference there...

```
public static void writeLine(OutputStream w, etc...) throws IOException {

    :
    sb.append("\n");
    String str = sb.toString();
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    w.write(bytes);
}
```

I highly recommend using a library for CSV files, such as http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ as they provide lots of great functionality.

Comment: Jamie I need your one more help. Now i have created one array[it contains some values.] and  that values are stored in a string. So now i want that string should be print in a specific excel cell(field) where i want. So how do i do that ? can you give me some clue you knew my previous work.